# Union of two sets that are connected in the closure is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are connected subsets of a topological space $X$ such that $A \cap cl(B)$ is non-empty. I want to show that $A \cup B$ is connected.

I can do this, but only if I assume that $X$ is Hausdorff. Because suppose I take a continuous $f: A \cup B \to\{ 0,1\}$ such that $f=0$ on $A$ and $f=1$ on $B$, then $f^{-1} (0) = B$ but in a Hausdorff space, $\{0\}$ is closed and so the pre-image must be closed, and it contains $B$ and so $\text{cl}(B)$ must be in the pre-image of $f$ and then we get that $f$ must be $0$ on $B$ also.

But is this true more generally without $X$ being Hausdorff?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing fine. Your proof only needs $\{0,1\} $ to be Hausdorff (which it is!).  You don't need the domain to be Hausdorff for this to work.

Comment: Ah yes of course! I didn't realise that! What topology do we actually give $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: For the purpose of connectedness, it's aimed to have the discrete topology.